# Two-way robocopy batch file

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have an USB flash drive where I have a folder called X which has always to be like folder Y on my notebook and vice versa, depending on the latest actions. For example, if I delete something in folder Y, it has also to be deletd in folder X (as soon as the flash drive is plugged in) and vice versa. If I add a folder or a file in X, it has also to be added in Y, as soon as the flash drive is plugged in.

Now I made a short batch script using robocopy:

```
@echo off
robocopy "D:\AC ActiveZone Mobile" "C:\AC ActiveZone" /MIR
PAUSE
```

The ActiveZone Mobile folder is our folder X and the ActiveZone is our folder Y.
The problem now is, that this seems not to be a two way synchronization. I will demonstrate that:

1.) Both folders and their subfolders and files are ident
2.) Created new file T1 in folder X
3.) Created new file T2 in folder Y
4.) Ran the script

Result: Instead of having T1 and T2 in both folders X and Y, I only have T1 in both folders X and Y now.

Also, (after first test above) if I delete T1 in folder Y and run the script, all I get is a new T1 in folder Y. But the delete action of T1 in Y is not older but newer than the creation of T1 in X. I want that T1 is also deleted in X instead of T1 being copied from X to Y.

How to get this done with a batch script?

Comment: robocopy is the wrong tool for this for several reasons. First, it won't copy files which are open which is going to be a real problem. It is also not a sync tool. Simply copying both directions does not make it one either. You need something that'll look at modified time stamps. Look at SyncToy: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155 or rsync: http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html or GDrive: https://drive.google.com/#my-drive

Comment: @krowe - probably you should make your comment an answer. Personally, I would accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Um, easy. Just run it two ways, excluding older files:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Two way mirror between %1 and %2, continue?
PAUSE
robocopy %2 %1 /E /DST /FFT /XO /XJ
robocopy %1 %2 /E /DST /FFT /XO /XJ
```

This should preserve the newer copy if file exist in both locations. I use /DST and /FFT because NTFS/FAT32 timestamp differences often cause false invalid compares otherwise. I also personally exclude Thumbs.db, desktop.ini etc.

If you want to delete non existing files you have to decide which is the "master" location, put it on the second line and change /E to /MIR instead. I think your idea of knowing if a file was deleted from one or the other as opposed to one simply not having a file the other has is impossible without some kind of tracking which is beyond what robocopy can do.

Comment: Re: "you have to decide which is the "master" location, put it on the second line and change /E to /MIR instead"... I don't think this would work. The first line would recreate the file in your "master," wouldn't it?

Comment: This will not work, one server will always overwrite the changes in the second one